# Can I have a logical AND inside an array formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet like the following

```
ID|AVAILABILITY|PRICE
1 |1           |10,00
1 |1           |15,00
1 |0           |12,00
2 |1           |10,00
```

And in the same worksheet **I do the following in MIN PRICE to get Minimun Price of available only products**

**I Save it as array formula**

```
ID|MIN PRICE
1 |=MIN(IF(AND(table1[AVAILABILITY]=1;table1[ID]=L2);table1[PRICE]))
2 |
```

But I get 0,
is there any work around on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need the `AND` in this case, just:

`{=MIN(IF(A:A=1;IF(B:B=1;C:C)))}`

See [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-if-multiple-criteria) for more information about this!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this array formula:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use *Excel for Office 365, Excel for Office 365 for Mac, Excel 2019 or Excel 2019 for Mac* you can use the [MINIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599).

If you use an older Excel version you can try to replace it with.

With 1 criterion, you could use these.

- MAXIFS:  `=MAX(INDEX(range-(criterion<>criterion_range)*1E300,0))`
- MINIFS:  `=MIN(INDEX(range+(criterion<>criterion_range)*1E300,0))`

That is, if the criterion isn't met, subtract/add a huge number to put the corresponding value from range out of consideration. These aren't array formulas.

For 2 or more criteria,

- MAXIFS:  `=MAX(IF(criterion1=criterion1_range,IF(criterion2=criterion2_range,range)))`
- MINIFS:  `=MIN(IF(criterion1=criterion1_range,IF(criterion2=criterion2_range,range)))`

The idea of the nested IF calls is that when the 1st criterion isn't satisfied, there's no need to check subsequent criteria. This performs the fewest number of comparisons. The ideal is to put the least frequently satisfied criterion 1st, then the next least frequently satisfied criterion, and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately I use excel 2010, but I think i will upgade shortly

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a VBA code. Any corrections all clarifications are welcome!

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastrowA As Long, LastrowE As Long, i As Long, ID As Long, Availability As Long, y As Long
    Dim LowestPrice As Double
    Dim strValues As String
    Dim arr As Variant, element As Variant, IDarr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        strValues = ""

        For i = 2 To LastrowA

            ID = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Availability = .Range("B" & i).Value

            If Availability > 0 And (InStr(strValues, ID) = 0) Then
                If i = LastrowA Then
                    strValues = strValues & ID
                Else
                    strValues = strValues & ID & "|"
                End If
            End If

        Next i

        arr = Split(strValues, "|")

        For Each element In arr

            IDarr = element
            LowestPrice = 0

            For y = 2 To LastrowA
                If CStr(.Range("A" & y).Value) = IDarr Then
                    If LowestPrice = 0 Then
                        LowestPrice = .Range("C" & y).Value
                    Else:
                        If LowestPrice > .Range("C" & y).Value Then
                            LowestPrice = .Range("C" & y).Value
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next y

            LastrowE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

            .Range("E" & LastrowE + 1).Value = IDarr
            .Range("F" & LastrowE + 1).Value = LowestPrice

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]